# Lotus Notes - Fails to move inbox article to subfolder

Tags: email, lotus-notes

Lotus Notes 8.5 - yuck!

User is trying to move an email from the Inbox into a subfolder and is using the menu option (not dragging & dropping) the email simply fails to move.  It just appears again in the inbox. Drag and drop has the same effect!

I have checked that it is a failure to move and not just a copy/delete issue.

I am not a Notes adminstrator, being more of a MS Exchange administrator by career path and have no idea what to be looking for.

Comment: Might have better luck posting this kind of question in a Lotus Notes forum.

Comment: Think it might actually be a Blackberry Server issue

Comment: This is an administrator issue, and it would be better suited on ServerFault, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a Blackberry issue - sychronisation settings had been played with by the user